# Is it possible to limit future Supreme Court justices to judges seated on the federal appellate bench without a constitutional amendment?

Tags: united-states, constitution, supreme-court

> Some judges worried that random appointments could result in
> lower-quality Supreme Court justices.
>
> “(J)ust because someone is on the Court of Appeals does NOT mean they
> are SCOTUS material,” argued Judge Bob Scott of the Johnson County,
> Kansas, District Court. But Circuit Court Commissioner Sam Filippo of
> Saxon, Wisconsin, had the opposite view: “If a judge has made it to
> the Circuit Court of Appeals,” he wrote, “she/he is probably qualified
> to sit on the Supreme Court.”
>
> Others pointed out that limiting future Supreme Court justices to
> judges seated on the federal appellate bench would eliminate potential
> nominees from lower federal courts, state courts, law professors and
> lawyers, all of whom have made distinguished Supreme Court justices in
> the past.
>
> And the objections didn’t end there. Here are some of the others:
>
> · Setting up the proposed scheme would likely require a constitutional
> amendment.

https://www.judges.org/news-and-info/judges-pan-the-idea-of-a-supreme-court-built-by-random-selection/

Is it possible to limit future Supreme Court justices to judges seated on the federal appellate bench without a constitutional amendment? The article seemed to suggest that restricting who can be nominated to become a Supreme Court justice would likely require an amendment to the constitution, but didn't reject the idea that it could be done without one. If it is indeed the case, what mechanisms can be employed to enact such a limitation without adding an amendment to the constitution?

Comment: [Article II, Section 2, Clause 2 of the Constitution](https://constitution.congress.gov/browse/essay/artII-S2-C2-3-5/ALDE_00013096/) is the relevant rule: the President "shall nominate, and by and with the Advice and Consent of the Senate, shall appoint ... Judges of the supreme Court".

Comment: I think this question would be improved with adding context to the question. In a year, the average visitor would be even less familiar with the recent change. A sentence or two establishing context would help preserve the meaning of the quote.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Supreme Court Justice appointments have to be approved by the Senate. The Constitution doesn't say what criteria they should or shouldn't use.

So the Senate can simply pass a rule saying they'll only approve Supreme Court Justices who have been appellate judges.

Of course, since it's just a rule, it can easily be rescinded. A Constitutional amendment would be more permanent.

Comment: Similarly, President can only nominate candidates who have been appellate judges, which again - the next President could do something else.

Comment: I don't think that's really comparable, since it's just a personal decision and POTUS could change their mind at any time. It's no different from saying "I'm planning on nominating a woman for the next open seat." Senate rules require collective action to establish and change, so they're harder to do on a whim.

Comment: ?? What's your source for the claim about the Equal Protection clause? What does that have to do with judicial nominees?

Comment: https://jud.ct.gov/HistoricalSociety/Rights.pdf "The constitutional right to equal protection bars the government from passing laws or
taking official actions that treat similarly-situated people or groups of people differently." @TenthJustice

Comment: But what does that have to do with judicial nominations? The President/Senate can nominate/confirm whoever they want.

Comment: @TenthJustice Confirming is an "official action". If the only reason they reject a nominee is because they're African-American, that would be unconstitutional discrimination. Of course, proving it might be difficult. But they certainly couldn't pass a rule that says they won't approve any black Justices.

Comment: "I think the only restriction would be if they violated the Equal Protection clause, so they can't discriminate against protected classes (e.g. based on race)." There is no such restriction.

Comment: Did you see the quote about "taking official actions" in my above comment? Is that website wrong? Or is confirming a justice not "taking official actions"? @ohwilleke

Comment: @Barmar Nominating and confirming justices are non-justiciable political questions. The "official actions" referred to are justiciable decisions of executive branch officials. To the extent that the website implies otherwise, it is wrong.

Comment: @ohwilleke Actually, that page is only talking about the 14th Amendment, which restricts states. The Federal govt is covered by the 5th Amendment's due process and equal protection clauses. However, I'm not a legal scholar like you, I'm not familiar with concepts like "justiciable decisions".

Comment: [here](https://digitalcommons.law.scu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1787&context=lawreview) is a Santa Clara Law Review article on equal protection, but I'm not going to read 50 pages looking for these details to understand it in full.

Comment: I've removed that part of my answer.

Comment: @ohwilleke The article has one short paragraph under "Is the claim justiciable" and it doesn't explain the concept for a layman like me. So I don't understand why actions of the Senate are not justiciable, but I take your word for it.

Comment: @ohwilleke I've now read https://digitalcommons.law.scu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1787&context=lawreview but I still don't understand why this wouldn't be justiciable.

Comment: @Barmar Basically because the U.S. Supreme Court has decided as a matter of constitutional law doctrine that decisions allocated to the "political branches" in the constitution can't be second guessed by the courts.